# What order should I watch Love, Chunibyo & Other Delusions in?

Tags: love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions

I would like to watch Love, Chunibyo & Other Delusions, but I'm not sure where to start.

What is the watching order of the series?

Comment: -1: you can find information about the names of the various anime adaptations on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love,_Chunibyo_%26_Other_Delusions). Moreover Crunchyroll's page for either season states whether it is season 1 or 2, and gives a link to the other season.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First Season: [Love, Chunibyo & Other Delusions!](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=14448)

Second Season: [Love, Chunibyo & Other Delusions! -Heart Throb-](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=15622)

Side Story [Love, Chunibyo & Other Delusions! Ren Lite](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=15781) (ONA)

Start with season 1.

Comment: While we're here, there's also a series of "Lite" shorts for the first season and a recap movie that should be watched between seasons 1 and 2.