# In what order should I watch the various parts of Love, Chuunibyou & other Delusions?

Tags: love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions

Now I noticed that this question has been slightly answered before but for absolute clarity, I need to know.

I came across these titles.

- Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!
- Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Lite
- Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Ren
- Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Ren Lite
- Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Ren Specials
- Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Ren: The Rikka Wars
- Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! The Movie Lite

Now because of my lack of knowledge as far as OVAs, ONAs, base series, and movies go in the anime genre exactly what is the chronological order of this list? And is it missing any titles from this series?

Oh, and I just finished the first season and if anything I know that I am supposed to watch the first lite series next right? Then the movie? (Ren specials and Rikka Wars, what order are these in?)

Comment: (Adding a link to where OP presumably saw this question "slightly answered" before: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19441/)

Answer (score 15):

First, watch *Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!* - this is the first TV season. Either at the same time or immediately afterwards, watch *Lite* - these are a bunch of short comedic sketches that occur at roughly the same time chronologically, but don't have any impact on the plot.

After you've watched the first season, watch the episode-length OVA that goes with it (not on your list; you'll probably find it titled "Kirameki no Slapstick Noel"). Not plot-critical, but fun.

It also makes sense to watch the *Depth of Field* shorts for the first season (not on your list) sometime after watching the first season; these are fun but completely plot-irrelevant.

Then, you may or may not want to watch *The Movie* (not on your list) - aside from a couple isolated scenes, it's mostly a recap of the first season. The added scenes are pretty fun, though, so you might like to just skim those. Whether or not you watch the movie, watch *The Movie Lite*, which is another short comedic sketch.

This is the point at which you start watching the second TV season, *Ren*. During or after watching *Ren*, watch *Ren Lite* and *Ren Specials* (in whichever order), both of which are non-plot-critical and not directly related to one another.

Finally, watch *Ren: The Rikka Wars*, which is an episode-length OVA, like its first season counterpart.

Comment: Is there anywhere to legally watch the *Depth of Field* shorts in English? I have the US DVD release for Series I and they don't seem to be on there, though the *Lite* sketches are included.

Comment: @Torisuda Beats me. The [Japanese Blu-ray](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E4%B8%AD%E4%BA%8C%E7%97%85%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E6%81%8B%E3%81%8C%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-7-Blu-ray-%E7%A6%8F%E5%B1%B1%E6%BD%A4/dp/B009Z8RYKM/) has them (without English subtitles, of course), but if Sentai decided not to put it on their release, I guess you're SOL.

Comment: Since this answer was posted, the series has grown another movie, _Take on me_. It looks to be a sequel to _Ren_ and its OVA.

Answer (score 2):

During a rewatch of the series, I again made the mistake of watching the recap movie after the second season, which is why I'm interested in writing an answer here. It also seems this question's answer hasn't been updated since the second movie came out. I have the ultimate collection DVD, so I'll be basing my answer on that. Sentai's release does not contain *Depth of Field: Ai to Nikushimi Gekijō* or *Heated Table Series: Kotatsu*, and I haven't watched these, so I'll only be noting them at the end.

## Proper viewing order:

1. **Love, Chunibyo & Other Delusions**. First series/season. Episodes 1-12.
2. **Chunibyo Lite**. These are six shorts. You can watch them during or after the first season. If you have the DVDs, you might want to watch them after episodes 1-9 for convenience, as they're contained on the same disc.
3. The Christmas OVA: **"Glimmering... Explosive Festival (Slapstick Noel)"**
4. The first film: **Love, Chunibyo & Other Delusions the Movie: Rikka Takanashi Revision**. This is a recap movie, however, the beginning and end contain new content. I can't stress enough that this content should be watched *before* the second series, as it sets up some of the events. It's not exactly necessary to understanding the second series, but if you're going to be watching this movie at all, before *Heart Throb* is the right time to do so, not after. There are around three new narration lines contained during the recap part, as well as a song part showing the characters, but feel free to skip the rest of the movie if that doesn't interest you.
5. **Chunibyo Lite: "My Older Brother 2"**. This is part of the *Lite* series, but it's contained on the same disc as the recap movie (It was probably shown in theaters with the movie). As far as I can tell, it's the only one with an English dub. There's going to be a third "My Older Brother" later, so that's another reason to put in the disc for the recap movie. I'll note, however, that even though I'm saying that, it isn't actually that important to watch them in the proper order, so watch them as 1, 3, 2 if it's more convenient.
6. **Love, Chunibyo & Other Delusions Heart Throb**. This is the second series/season. It contains twelve episodes just like the first.
7. **Chunibyo Ren Lite**. A second series of six shorts. You can watch these at any point during or after the second season. Again, they're contained on the same disc as episodes 1-9, so after those might be the most convenient time.
8. The second OVA: "**Playback of... the Wicked Eye's Apocalypse (The Rikka Wars)"**.
9. **Kotatsu Photo Session** shorts. These are the three shorts that go with the second movie. They're a bit lackluster compared to some of the other stuff, so while I think they're worth watching once, you might want to skip them on a rewatch. There's a part in the middle that's always the same, where they're explaining the rules for taking pictures, so you might want to skip that part at least. There is actual dialogue during the still-frame part, so don't skip that (unless you want to, because it is still a bit boring). These are meant to be watched before the movie, but honestly, it doesn't really matter when you watch them.
10. **Love, Chunibyo, & Other Delusions: Take On Me**. This is the final movie.

Now for the shorts series you probably won't be watching at all (Though you'll wish you could!): **Depth of Field: Ai to Nikushimi Gekijō**, and **Heated Table Series: Kotatsu**. These are not contained in the Sentai English release. If you get a chance to watch these, it'll probably be after you're done watching everything else. They're shorts, so it's probably fine to watch them whenever.

## Chronological Order

If you're interested in watching in chronological order (not that I'd recommend it for a first time viewing), you'll want to watch these shorts before even starting episode 1.

1. From **Lite**: "Wicked Eye: Daybreak Chapter" (episode 2), "My Older Brother" (episode 3),  "My Older Brother 2" (episode 7, contained on second movie disc).
2. From **Ren Lite**: "Wicked Eye: Storm Chapter" (episode 3), "My Older Brother 3: Camping Chapter" (episode 5), "Summoning an Archangel" (episode 6).

Everything else will be the same as above.

Comment: Got the episode titles from Wikipedia for convenience. I might put the DVDs in to check on those parentheses parts.

Comment: I'm guessing it's denoting official English title vs Japanese translation.